# Limit user to one window for specific domain

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to find a way for a website to find out if a user already has another window open of that same website. I tried AJAX setting a flag as soon as window opens but UNSETTING this flag never worked properly (on closing the window or quit browser).

Comment: The only sure way I can think of is having an AJAX request which continues to ping back to the server every 10 secs or so, and only from that page. Therefore confirming they still have the page open.

Comment: What do You want to do, when he or she tries to open a second window?

Comment: you want this to work also when the user uses different browsers e.g one window in chrome and one in mozilla? if not you can use local storage. tell you thought to give a complete answer

Comment: It only needs to work in the SAME browser. On opening a second window I just will not have the long polls that usually would happen (together with a little note saying that there is already another window open). @mraspogos: Wouldn't the user need to approve the local storage? I don't want to annoy them  ...

Comment: I tried localStorage but the data does not seem to be accessible cross broswer windows (same browser, of course). sessionStorage did not work either.